# Interacting with the server API from android application

Tags: android

Can anyone explain for me or guide me through the basics that i have to know on how to interact with the server API from Android Application?

Any good website that teaches beginners because am new to this thing and am quite lost

Answer (score 1):

If it is a restful API that you will be interacting with, I would highly recommend using RetroFit.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Square have excellent documentation and the examples should be easy to follow. If you get stuck you can always post on here under the Retrofit tag which has a fairly large following.

Volley is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Volley networking library http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://lakjeewa.blogspot.com/2014/05/simple-android-client-server-application.html) shows how to make simple client-server app right now.

[Here](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/) and [here](https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)  you can read description during making client-server app.

I found those links very useful for me when I started to learn this topic.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started I've have a sample app [Link](https://github.com/kodered/Github_Widget) which uses Github's REST and fetch the result and display it in android List. It is a basic one without any authentication. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Recently android has introduced a library to parse json. It is called [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

Volley offers the following benefits:

- Automatic scheduling of network requests.
- Multiple concurrent network connections.
- Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache
  coherence.
- Support for request prioritization.
- Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can
  set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.
- Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
- Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with
  data fetched asynchronously from the network.
- Debugging and tracing tools.

Tutorial which I used is [Volley tutorial for json parsing](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/). Another link is [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/)

Hope this helps you.